How to implement UUPS with a solidity contract having VRF and automation features?
I am developping a solidity contract with those inheritances:

ERC20
ERC20FlashMint
VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus
AutomationCompatibleInterface

pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@chainlink/contracts/node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/interfaces/IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";

contract ExampleV1 is ERC20, ERC20FlashMint, VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
...
}

I also created a javascript Test file to be able to deploy and simulate all the functions calls of the contract.
I would like to be able to create a new contract ExampleV2 but i struggle to add UUPS capability of Openzeppelin.
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/ERC20Upgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20BurnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20PausableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";

If i try to add them into the contract ExampleV1, i get a lot of conflicts telling me that functions exist more than once.
Can someone help me understand how to create a proxy contract with UUPS that will help me upgrade the ExampleV1 to ExampleV2 and also add the code in Javascript to be able to have a complete test in Hardhat deploying first the ExampleV1  and then the ExampleV2.
Thank you for your help.
If needed more information. I would be happy to add details.
Expected result would be:
Develop ExampleV1  (upgradeable)
In the javascript test code:

deploy ExampleV1
call ExampleV1 functions

Develop ExampleV2 (upgrdeable)
In the javascript test code:

deploy ExampleV1
call ExampleV1 functions
In the same address deploy ExampleV2
call ExampleV2 functions

